# LEVEL connections

Tags: combinatorics, visual

How many ways are there to form the word 'LEVEL' by following the lines?

[image]

(You can't go back on yourself but apart from that you can move in any direction and can end up on the same 'L' as you started with)

Comment: Does it count only once if we start from either left or right (or up down), or twice, one for each starting L?

Comment: Are you allowed to reuse a vertex without going back on a line, e.g. starting and ending on the same 'L'?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder yes you are

Comment: And do palindromes count? i.e. the exact same path but going in the opposite direction.  For example, could a diagonal be 2 paths?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder that counts as going back on yourself

Comment: I mean as 2 different paths, e.g. is the path going top-left to bottom-right a different path from the one going bottom-right to top-left?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder Yes it is

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without allowing backtracking along edges

> $60$

Since

> **"L"** only appears at the four corners, and staring at any corner there are fifteen paths to form the word. $15\times 4=60$

The paths

> From a corner there is $1$ way to reach the opposite corner, $5$ ways to reach each of the $2$ adjacent corners, and $4$ ways to come back without back tracking along edges ($2$ directions around the $2$ small triangles). $1+2\times 5+4=15$
> [image: flashy path gif]

Comment: could you somehow show the paths?

Answer (score 5):

There are

> 60 ways.

Proof.

> From the top left to the top right L there are 5 ways.
>
>  1
>  `'L E V E L'`
>
>  2
>  `'L E V   L'`
>  `'      E  '`
>
>  3
>  `'L   V E L'`
>  `'  E      '`
>
>  4
>  `'L   V   L'`
>  `'  E   E  '`
>
>  5
>  `'L       L'`
>  `'  E   E  '`
>  `'    V    '`
>
>  And another 5 ways similarly to the bottom left corner.
>
>  There are also 4 ways of returning to the same position:
>
>  Two paths (one clockwise and one anticlockwise)
>  `'L E V'`
>  `'  E  '`
>
>  Two paths (one clockwise and one anticlockwise)
>  `'L   '`
>  `'E  E'`
>  `'V   '`
>
>  Finally, there is one way to go diagonally to the bottom right corner, which makes for a total of 15. Times 4 for all the corners and we get 60.

Comment: You can do code blocks in quotes. It'll look better than separate pre blocks.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Cheers, that's a good idea I hadn't thought of.